# How to take out only certain records from a properties file using java

Tags: java

I have a **sample.properties** file containing below details:

```
Id = 212208386
Dept = INSTORE
Name = Hello Bye
itemsSold = 2.0

Id = 212208324
Dept = WEB
Name = Mr Perfect
itemsSold = 2.0
Misc = None

Id = 212899004
Dept = INSTORE
Name = AB CD EF
itemsSold = 2.0

Id = 213112314
Dept = INSTORE
Name = No Please
itemsSold = 2.0
Misc = Sale Offer
```

and so on.

Can you please help me with a java code that reads this file, takes a Id input ( Say, ID= 212208324) and gives the respective record as the output

i,e if i provide Id= 212208324 and File = sample.properties , it should provide me below output:

```
Id = 212208324
Dept = WEB
Name = Mr Perfect
itemsSold = 2.0
Misc = None
```

Comment: checkout this url https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

Comment: Your file has multiple non-unique keys, so you will probably have to manually parse the file.

Comment: you're right,i'am sorry ,your',yes  propreties not support duplicate key ,